# URL While loop python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to improve my current code so where I make a loop that if a url is equal to a certain address then it will just loop till the url is not equal to that address.  I am just using google as an example. The mouse will basically be clicking onto nothing so the webpage will stay the same till a specif time which will then have a button where the mouse is trying to click. That will then make the webpage url a different url which is when I want the rest of the script to run. I don't know the exact time the webpage will update so I need to make a loop so it loops till the button on the webpage appears and the mouse is able to click it...

```
def login(self):
        bot = self.bot
        bot.get('www.google.com')
        time.sleep(1)
        email = bot.find_element_by_name('user[email]')
        password = bot.find_element_by_name('user[password]')
        email.clear()
        password.clear()
        email.send_keys(self.username)
        password.send_keys(self.password)
        password.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
        time.sleep(1)
        mouse = Controller()
        mouse.position = (408, 333)
        mouse.click(Button.left, 1)
        time.sleep(2)

        while url_main == 'www.google.com':
        try:
            time.sleep(2)
        except:
            break

        def repeat():
            mouse.click(Button.left, 1) , time.sleep(1)
            mouse.position = (853, 323)
            mouse.click(Button.left, 1) , time.sleep(1)
            mouse.position = (902, 162)
            mouse.click(Button.left, 1) , time.sleep(0)
```

Comment: This code is fine, but where are you trying to change `url_main` to anything else?

Comment: That code will do exactly what you have described. It's probably not going to do anything useful unless the value of `url_main` is being changed somewhere though.

Comment: so what im trying to get is a module to check the url so say url.module = 'google.com' so I need a module that can check the url and if the url is equal to a certain address then it will loop till it refreshes and it is a different address

Comment: please post remaining code to give us more context. Now it merely code optimization... well appreachiated at an SO sister site named "code review".

Comment: @DanielBirdsall It would really improve your question, and help people to answer it, if you'd ask a specific, precise question. Your question mentions something you're trying to do, but you don't actually ask a question that can be answered.

Comment: sorry, basically I am wanting to find a module that can read a url and if anyone knows of any that would be great

Comment: Read a url from where?

Answer (score 0):

I would do this:

```
import time

# Python3 code to iterate over a list 
list = ['www.google.com', 'www.google.com', 'www.google.com', 'www.cnn.com', 'www.google.com'] 

# Using for loop 
for i in list: 
    if i == 'www.google.com':
        print(i)
        time.sleep(2)
    else:
        print(i)
        break
```

But your question must be more specific.
Why are you doing this? Where is your script reding from? From a list? from a file?

I don't understand what you are trying to archive.

Comment: I have edited my code to include what I am trying to do. I am just using google as an example. The mouse will basically be clicking onto nothing so the webpage will stay the same till a specif time which will then have a button where the mouse is trying to click. That will then make the webpage url a different url which is when I want the rest of the script to run. I don't know the exact time the webpage will update so I need to make a loop so it loops till the button on the webpage appears and the mouse is able to click it